# Morera's theorem for equilateral triangles

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\Omega$ be a planar domain and $f:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ a continuous function. If $$\int_{\partial T}f(z)dz=0,$$ for every closed equilateral triangle $T$ in $\Omega$, then $f$ is holomorphic. I have tried to approximate triangles  with equilateral triangles and use Morera's theorem but this didn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: What have you tried? Please tell us what facts about holomorphic functions do you know, so that we can give a proof based on these facts.

Comment: I am a graduate student, so I know some things about complex analysis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f$ is $C^1$, then $$0=\int_{\partial T}f(z)dz=2i\int\int_{T}\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial\overline{z}}(z)dxdy.$$

Thus, if $T$ is an equilateral triangle with side length $s$ and orthocenter $w$ $$\dfrac{4}{s^2\sqrt{3}}\int\int_{T}\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial\overline{z}}dxdy=0$$
Making $s\rightarrow 0$, we have that $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial\overline{z}}(w)=0$. Therefore, $f$ is holomorphc.

If $f$ is just continuous, then $f*\dfrac{\varphi_r}{\pi r^2}\rightarrow f$ uniformly on the compact subsets of $\Omega$, where $\varphi_r$ is the characteristic function of a disk in $\Omega$. Also, $f*\dfrac{\varphi_r}{\pi r^2}$ is $C^1$. Using Fubini's theorem we have the same condition for $f*\dfrac{\varphi_r}{\pi r^2}$. Thus, $f*\dfrac{\varphi_r}{\pi r^2}$ are holomorphic. Weiestrass theorem completes the proof.

Comment: Can you expain a little bit more?

Comment: It seems right, but I will check it in order to thoroughly understand it. Thanks!

Comment: @Chris Apostol, what is $*$?